# Regex to match on ports. Seperated with either a dash or comma

Tags: powershell, regex

I'm trying to get a working regex syntax to match the following values. The field is able to contain either

1. Comma-separated values or a single value. Such as "22" or "22,456"
2. A range of ports with a dash. Such as "22-600"

With values possible from 1 to 65535

**Attempts**

Matches a single port correctly, however doesn't support a "," or "-"

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?:,(?1))*$
```

Doesn't match a single port but does match multiple comma seperated ports

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?:,(?1))(?:,(?1))*$
```

Doesn't match a single port but does match a port range

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?:-(?1))(?:(?1))*$
```

Comment: Can you use a PowerShell function instead of simply a very complicated regex?

Comment: I can, But I'm trying to use a JSON Schema to validate the JSON files that come through. That's what management wants to happen so it's more of a "proper" test instead of some custom PowerShell function

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})-(?1)|(?1)(,(?1))+$
```

Your first regex hat `[0-9]` as last option, which allows 0 as value. I changed that and added the other options.

See https://regexr.com/5dvdk